# Timer not firing after page navigation

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone-8

I have this class to run functions in some amount of time:

```
namespace Test
{
    public static class At
    {
        private static void ExecuteDelayedAction(object o)
        {
            (o as Action).Invoke();
        }

        public static void Do(Action action, TimeSpan delay, int interval = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            new Timer(new TimerCallback(At.ExecuteDelayedAction), action, Convert.ToInt32(delay.TotalMilliseconds), interval);
        }
        public static void Do(Action action, DateTime dueTime, int interval = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            if (dueTime >= DateTime.Now) Do(action, dueTime - DateTime.Now, interval);
        }
        public static void Do(Action action, int delay, int interval = Timeout.Infinite)
        {
            Do(action, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay), interval);
        }
    }
}
```

And also in my application I have two pages - `Login.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml`. Just for test purposes  I've puth the following code in `MainPage` constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    At.Do(delegate { Debug.WriteLine("MainPage"); }, 5000);
}
```

My problem is as follows: if application opens `MainPage` first then timer works fine and delegate gets executed. If, however, application opens `Login` first and then navigates to `MainPage` then timer just fails silently. Why is it happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the timer you are creating is being garbage-collected (GC'ed), as you are not holding a reference to it anywhere but just dropping the reference to the newly created timer.

As navigating between pages will cause quite a bit of memory to be created, a GC may be triggered then.

Try fixing it by keeping a reference to the timer object around. I would create a `Do` class instance which you could hide a private timer inside, and keep a reference to that.  However if you want to keep your current static class design you could just return an object that is the timer.

```
    public static object Do(Action action, TimeSpan delay, int interval = Timeout.Infinite)
    {
        var t = new Timer(new TimerCallback(At.ExecuteDelayedAction), action, Convert.ToInt32(delay.TotalMilliseconds), interval);
        return t;
    }
```

and then you need to store a reference to your timer with your page.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.doObject = At.Do(delegate { Debug.WriteLine("MainPage"); }, 5000);
}
```

Of course, if the `MainPage` is GC'ed then your timer will be too, but you can fix that by changing the scope of your timer to what is appropriate for the action you want to run.